# max(dict, dict.get) when dict items are NamedTuple objects

Tags: python, dictionary, max, namedtuple

My goal is to find the id of the element in the dictionary, where similarity parameter is the highest.

I'm not sure I understand why these 2 methods are working identically and I would really appreciate it if someone could explain.

Here is my python 3.6 code:

```
class ParentCandidate(NamedTuple):
    similarity: float
    title: str


c1 = ParentCandidate(0.875, 'longest title 1')
c2 = ParentCandidate(1, 'title 2')
c3 = ParentCandidate(0.9, 'title 3')
c4 = ParentCandidate(1.1, 'title 4')
c5 = ParentCandidate(0.5, 'title 5')

candidates = {1: c1, 2: c2, 3: c3, 4: c4, 5: c5}

closest_method1 = max(candidates, key=candidates.get)
closest_method2 = max(candidates, key=lambda sim: candidates[sim].similarity)
print(closest_method1, closest_method2)
assert closest_method1 == closest_method2
```

Second method works exactly as planned and it seems clear how we identify max similarity value as we are referring directly to it.
Whilst I simply do not understand how the max() function is able to do it's job when it receives NamedTuple objects for comparison.

Comment: If `ParentCandidate`s were `tuple`s instead of `NamedTuple`s, would you still have a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplify it. Take `NamedTuple`s and `max` right out of the equation:

```
>>> (0.9, 'title 3') > (0.5, 'title 5')
True
```

Tuples can be directly compared. Initially, the first elements are checked. Since `0.9` is greater than `0.5` above, the first tuple is considered to be greater. If the first elements were the same though, it would move onto the second elements and checks them. It repeats that process until it finds one set of elements where one is greater, or they're considered to be equal.

---

```
max(candidates, key=candidates.get)
```

This is basically expanding on that idea and checking which of the `NamedTuple`s (which inherit the behavior from tuples) is the greatest. This effectively means it's checking the first element of the tuples, but note that if you have two elements with the same `similarity`, it will then move onto the `title` element and do lexicographical ordering on the strings! This is likely not what you want, so I'd skip using that variant.

Answer (score 2):

They're not exactly the same. The first method is comparing the whole tuple, the second is only comparing the `similarity` elements. The first method is equivalent to

```
closest_method = max(candidates, key=lambda sim: candidates[sim])
```

`candidates.get(x)` is equivalent to `candidates[x]` when `x` is a key of the dictionary. And since `max()` iterates over the key, the case where the key doesn't exist can't occur in this context (indexing raises an exception, `.get()` returns `None` by default).

If all the `similarity` elements are unique then there won't be a difference between the two methods. But if there are duplicate `similarity` values, the `.get()` method will compare the titles to order them.